# How to generate band-limited random noise with flat spectrum?

Tags: matlab, random, noise

How can I generate 500 ms worth of noise sampled at 1280 Hz, with a flat frequency distribution between 0.1 - 640 Hz and normally distributed amplitude values?

See the screenshot below for an illustration of the desired output.

[Timeplot of waveform, frequency distribution, and histogram of amplitudes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwpys.png)

Comment: Could you confirm that your post can be summarised as follows: "How can I generate 500 ms worth of noise sampled at 1280 Hz, with a flat frequency distribution between 0.1 - 640 Hz and normally distributed amplitude values?"

Comment: @Sheljohn yes, that is certainly a much more concise way of putting it! Apologies for my verbosity! The only addition I would make is that the amplitude values should be normally distributed in the range -500 to +500 (well, at least such as that 99.7% of amplitudes lie within the range above).

Comment: That is unnecessarily restrictive; any normally distributed output can be linearly rescaled to any desired range. I can edit your post to make it more concise, but would you like to do it instead?

Comment: Thank you, but that won't be necessary. I edited the post with your wording. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I also edited the title for clarity; I am working on an answer to your post, but essentially you just need to work in the Fourier domain. In the future, you should provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question, in order to show what you have tried and illustrate why it does not achieve what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of your question make the answer trivial:

- 640 Hz is exactly half of 1280 Hz, so this is the highest frequency (Nyquist) in the Fourier decomposition;
- 0.1 Hz is way below 1 / 500ms = 2Hz, which is the frequency resolution of your Fourier decomposition, and therefore the lowest positive frequency you can control.

So in your case, the "band-limited" constraint is trivial, and you can simply generate the desired noise with:

```
duration  = 500e-3;
rate      = 1280;
amplitude = 500;

npoints   = duration * rate;
noise     = amplitude * randn( 1, npoints ); % normally distributed white noise
time      = (0:npoints-1) / rate;
```

However, more generally, generating noise in a specific frequency band with constraints on spectrum shape (eg flat) and value statistics (eg normally distributed) can be difficult. There are two simple approximations I can think of:

- Working in the time-domain, first enforcing constraints on value statistics by drawing from the distribution of choice, and then filtering the resulting signal using a band-pass FIR filter for example. For this approximation, note that the filter will also affect the distribution of values, and so in general your constraints on value statistics will be poorly met unless you design the filter very carefully.
- Working backwards from the Fourier domain, first enforcing constraints on the amplitude coefficients, taking random noise for the phase, and using an inverse transform to come back to the time-domain. For this approximation, note that the phase distribution will affect the temporal distribution of values in non-trivial ways, depending on the amplitude constraints, and that if your sampling rate is much larger than your frequency cutoff, you might need to enforce constraints on harmonic amplitudes as well in order to avoid artefacts.